# AWS : Send only latest file from S3 to Amazon MQ

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on a project, where files would be getting added to S3. In S3 there is an option to get all the newly uploaded files.

I can add subscriptions for SQS, but how can I push any newly added file in S3 to Amazon MQ? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

S3 supports [event notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html) when objects are uploaded to S3 (and for other events).

Supported [destinations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#notification-how-to-event-types-and-destinations) are currently:

- SNS
- SQS
- AWS Lambda

I'm assuming that you want a reference to a new file to be sent to MQ (rather than the file itself, as you indicated). You could write a simple Lambda function to do that in response to an `s3:ObjectCreated:*` event.